# Handling of longitudinal (repeated measurements) data in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

There are indeed some nice features in the **dplyr** package by Hadley Wickham.

I wonder if functions in the package can solve the following issues, which relates to longitudinal data (repeated measurements on same individuals); a subject for which I find scarce tutorials on the Internet.

The data set looks like this:

```
test <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
  ID  AGE   YEAR_VISIT  BLOOD_PRESSURE  TREATMENT
  1 20  2000    130 3
  1 21  2001    129 2
  1 22  2002    145 3
  1 22  2002    130 2
  2 23  2003    NA  NA
  2 30  2010    150 2
  2 31  2011    110 3
  4 50  2005    140 3
  4 50  2005    130 3
  4 50  2005    NA  3
  4 51  2006    312 2
  5 27  2010    140 4
  5 28  2011    170 4
  5 29  2012    160 NA
  7 40  2007    120 NA
                   ")
```

ID is the variable that identifies a particular individual (multiple rows = repeated measurements).
AGE, YEAR_VISIT (year of examination), BLOOD_PRESSURE (continuous) and TREATMENT (type of treatment, categorical) is updated each registration.

I would like to do the following:

(1) identify and retain the first AGE and first YEAR_VISIT for each individual; this should generate two new variables, e.g called first_age and first_year.

2) create a new variable which is the updated mean value of the former and current value. This means that the updated blood pressure for the first observation is simply the current value; the next observation the updated value is equal to (former blood pressure value +current)/2. If current value is missing, then it should retain the former value (if there is one).

3) fill in missing values in categorical variable TREATMENT by carrying the former value onward (last observation carried forward).

I know thats more than one question, but it relates to the same topic, which is handling of longitudinal data.

I've done efforts to solve this myself without any success and perhaps more R users have the same difficulty?

**I've tried the following:**

Carry forward missing blood pressure and identify first observation for each individual

```
test4 <- test
test4$first <- !duplicated(test4$ID)
for(i in 2:nrow(test4)){
  if(!test4$first[i] & test4$ID[i] == test4$ID[i-1] & is.na(test4$BLOOD_PRESSURE[i])){
    test4$BLOOD_PRESSURE[i] <- test4$BLOOD_PRESSURE[i-1]
  }
}
test
test4
```

Updated mean value for blood pressure

```
test5 <- test
test5$UM <- rep(NA, nrow(test5))
test5$first <- !duplicated(test5$ID)
for(i in 1:nrow(test5)){
  if(test5$first[i]){
    test5$UM[i] <- test5$BLOOD_PRESSURE[i]
  }else{
    test5$UM[i] <- mean(c(test5$BLOOD_PRESSURE[i] , test5$UM[i-1]), na.rm=TRUE)
  }
}
test5
```

I believe thats quiet cumbersome to code, particularly since I'd like to update means and carry forward several variables...

As you point out, I'm new to R and really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think some of the down & close votes (none of those are mine) are for not "showing some effort". Every single one of your requirements are very doable with `dplyr` (with some help from `zoo`). Review `dplyr`'s `group_by` & `arrange` and `mutate` functions and check out `zoo`'s `na.locf` function.

Comment: What have you tried ? I am also just curious , why do you want to do it with `dplyr`? Is it more classy nowadays to do things using this package?

Comment: @agstudy: This one's pretty easy/elegant/readable with `dplyr`+`zoo`. I almost want to post a solution just for FAQ reference, but the OP has made virtually no sign of any attempt at a solution on their own.

Comment: @hrbrmstr elegant/readable are very subjective qualifiers. I understand that we can use `rollapply`+`na.locf`  from `zoo` package. But I just say that there is a kind of obsession to do things with `dplyr` package like it is the "R way" or the only way to do things. Better to learn how to do(at least try to do ) things with Base R before to use any other package.

Comment: @agstudy I think advising people to use base R before a package (regardless of who wrote it!) is nonsense. Use the package (base or otherwise) that allows you to solve the problem most effectively.

Comment: @hadley Indeed, one should use the best package that resolve the problem but my comment makes perfectly sense within the context of the OP question. The OP begin his question with "I wonder if functions in the package can solve the following issues" , he is not asking for the best method to resolve the problem, he wants to use a certain package (for some reason that I ignore), without providing any attempts using this package.Then,when you see his code I think that learning some R basics is better for him than using a new package with a particular notation.....

Comment: @hadley ..also when you see the final solution, (expect grouping) specially here as you see that the main question is resolved using zoo package.

Comment: It's a shame dplyr is not included in base R. It would have saved me so much time and effort. The package, despite it's strange name, makes R as easy to use as it should be. Unless you like the $ [] c("") thing. NB: the rollmeanr did not work, can't get the variable updated, after all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering solely in defense of my claims in the comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

test %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                                       # work on groups
  arrange(YEAR_VISIT) %>%                                # arrange by year
  mutate(first_age=min(AGE),                             # make col for min age
         first_year=min(YEAR_VISIT),                     # make col for min year
         bp_mean=mean(BLOOD_PRESSURE, na.rm=TRUE),       # make col for mean
         TREATMENT=na.locf(TREATMENT, na.rm=FALSE)) %>%  # use zoo's na.locf to fill in NAs
  ungroup()

##     Source: local data frame [15 x 8]
## 
##    ID AGE YEAR_VISIT BLOOD_PRESSURE TREATMENT first_age first_year  bp_mean
## 1   1  20       2000            130         3        20       2000 133.5000
## 2   1  21       2001            129         2        20       2000 133.5000
## 3   1  22       2002            145         3        20       2000 133.5000
## 4   1  22       2002            130         2        20       2000 133.5000
## 5   2  23       2003             NA        NA        23       2003 130.0000
## 6   2  30       2010            150         2        23       2003 130.0000
## 7   2  31       2011            110         3        23       2003 130.0000
## 8   4  50       2005            140         3        50       2005 194.0000
## 9   4  50       2005            130         3        50       2005 194.0000
## 10  4  50       2005             NA         3        50       2005 194.0000
## 11  4  51       2006            312         2        50       2005 194.0000
...
```

Even if you don't know R, It'd be hard to argue that's not readable & concise.

Caveat: the `NA`s in `TREATMENT` can be filled in "reverse", but the OP did not say that was a requirement.

Comment: Thanks @hrbmrstr!
As for the down votes; I often see down votes when folks don't attach their code attempts but often (particularly newbies, such as me) one doesn't have an adequate coding sample to present...
I tried your answer hrbrmrstr and it worked out beautifully, except from that blood pressure was not updated mean, it was overall mean. The updated mean is a new mean for each new observation for the same individual. I could not figure out how to do that myself neither..

Thanks again

Comment: I would use something like `rollmeanr(BLOOD_PRESSURE,2)` for the "updated mean".

Comment: @AdamRobinsson I downvote and vote to close the question because you ask many questions in the same time. This is really discouraged in SO. Without any attempt from your side , this looks like do it for me. Note I upvote once you added some code and I retract my closing vote also.

Comment: Thanks agstudy. I't appears that the rolling mean solved the final puzzle.

Thank you guys.